How to only add methods to class if type pack contains specific type?
I'm trying to create a class that can contain a type pack.
// Pack.hpp
template <typename... Types>
class Pack final
{
    Pack(const std::tuple<Types...> items) : items_(std::move(items)) {};

    std::tuple<Types...> items_;
};

But I would like Pack to expose some methods based on the Types inside of it. For example, I want to do this:
// Consumer.cpp
Person person{ ... };
Car car{ ... };
Pack<Person, Car> personAndCarPack{ { person, car } };
Pack<Person> personPack{ { person } };

// Ok
personAndCarPack.getCar();

// Ok
personAndCarPack.getPerson();

// Ok
personPack.getPerson();

// Shouldn't compile - getCar() shouldn't exist!
personPack.getCar();

I'm assuming I have to declare it more or less this way:
// Pack.hpp

template <typename... Types>
class Pack final 
{
    Pack(const std::tuple<Types...> items) : items_(std::move(items)) {};

    std::tuple<Types...> items_;

    Car getCar() 
    {
        return std::get<Car>(items_);
    }

    Person getPerson() 
    {
        return std::get<Person>(items_);
    }
};

But of course that exposes the methods in Pack regardless of the types.
The closest I've got is this:
typename std::enable_if<(std::is_same_v<Types, Car> && ...), Car>::type
getCar()
{
    return std::get<Car>(items_);
}

But it doesn't compile; I get
'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration

in the std::is_same_v() call.
I am probably misunderstanding how it all works. I've found some answers that are somewhat related, but none with the right combination of factors according to what I need.
Is it possible to implement this functionality at all? If so, how?

std::enable_if to conditionally compile a member function and Check if parameter pack contains a type


Is it possible to implement this functionality at all? If so, how?

Yes, it is possible. The minimal change ᕯsolution is without std::enable_if/ SFINAE.
// Method to get a Car from the Pack (enabled only if Car is in Types...)
template <typename T = Car>
constexpr auto getCar() -> decltype(std::get<Car>(items_))
{
    return std::get<Car>(items_);
}

// Method to get a Person from the Pack (enabled only if Person is in Types...)
template <typename T = Person>
constexpr auto getPerson() -> decltype(std::get<Person>(items_))
{
    return std::get<Person>(items_);
}

See live demo
ᕯ Keep in mind that the above does not disable the function from usage in unevaluated context (i.e. decltype(personPack.getCar()) x = personAndCarPack.getCar(); will still be valid).

Alternatively, with std::enable_if_t and std::disjunction, you might achieve the same effect as well.
// Method to get a Car from the Pack (enabled only if Car is in Types...)
template <typename T = Car>
constexpr auto getCar()
         -> std::enable_if_t<std::disjunction<std::is_same<Types, T>...>::value, T>
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, Car>, "T must be of type Car!");
    return std::get<T>(items_);
}

// Method to get a Person from the Pack (enabled only if Person is in Types...)
template <typename T = Person>
constexpr auto getPerson()
         -> std::enable_if_t<std::disjunction<std::is_same<Types, T>...>::value, T>
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, Person>, "T must be of type Person!");
    return std::get<T>(items_);
}

See live demo

(For future readers) Since c++20, however, the solution will be much simpler with requires constraints
// Method to get a Car from the Pack (enabled only if Car is in Types...)
constexpr auto getCar() requires (std::is_same_v<Types, Car> || ...)
{
    return std::get<Car>(items_);
}

// Method to get a Person from the Pack (enabled only if Person is in Types...)
constexpr auto getPerson() requires (std::is_same_v<Types, Person> || ...)
{
    return std::get<Person>(items_);
}

See live demo

With the first option the declarations are always visible, therefore sth like this:     decltype(personPack.getCar()) x = personAndCarPack.getCar(); will be possible

Nice! This does exactly what I needed. I tried so hard to make SFINAE work, I didn't even realize it would be possible without it. (Like @alagner mentioned, the declarations are visible - in both cases - but it's something I can live with since at least personPack.getCar() doesn't compile).
